# Problem with opening URL in popup with Safari Mobile on iPhone. Ignoring parameters

Tags: javascript, iphone, twitter, safari, popup

I'm building a web application (based on Phonegap) optimized for iPhone.
I have to integrate a popup which will open our twitter page and shouldn't fit to entire screen (for a simple navigation problem..how do a user should go back at full screen??).

I've noticed that Safari Mobile opens correctly the new page but ignores my window.load width/height parameters.

This is the incriminated js code :

> var twitterLink=$("#twitter a");
>   var url="http://mobile.twitter.com/test";
>   twitterLink.click(function(){
>     window.open(url,'name','(height=200),(width=150)');
>      return false;
>   });

I've just tried all other browsers on leopard and work!
My aim was embedding a Twitter Profile Page in the fastest way in a page of my app (which has a navigation bottom bar).
This morning I've tried with IFRAME , but with no luck...are not supported..
Then i've tried with  the new Twitter intent but has the same problem as  here in safari Mobile (ignoring parameters of popup)

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I believe that Safari mobile only runs in full screen mode! Have you been able to get any other safari mobile screens to appear in a smaller window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a known bug of Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

By my knowledge window.open accepts parameters without parentheses, so:

```
window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
```

this should work.

Comment: Are you sure? I usually do it with spaces and uses it

Comment: There are MANY browsers that doe not like the spaces. All legacy IEs for example